# How to custom mfBootstrapPaginator of angular-6-datatable component

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, angular6

I would like to customize angular6 datatable. By default it comes like that

[image]

But I want something like the screenshot below:

[image]

Could you tell me how to do it?.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I solved extending paginator class in a new module inside app folder and changing the template as I wanted. It´s working perfectly. I have run npm install the changes will never be gone. Its like overwriting files :). Thanks